# nativescript-sqlite plugin won't run on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, nativescript

I am having an issue running my nativescript app on iOS. I am using the `nativescript-sqlite` plugin within my app, which functions correctly on android, but on iOS it won't even get as far as building the app. Below is the output:

```
john-imac:nextra-test johnt$ tns emulate ios
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-insomnia for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-sqlite for ios.
Processing node_modules failed. Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ruby -e "require 'xcodeproj'; Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/johnt/Dropbox/NativeScript/nextra-test/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig').merge(Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/johnt/Dropbox/NativeScript/nextra-test/node_modules/nativescript-sqlite/platforms/ios/build.xcconfig')).save_as(Pathname.new('/Users/johnt/Dropbox/NativeScript/nextra-test/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig'))"
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:inrequire'
from -e:1:in `
```

Would anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I didn't have the correct `gem` installed.

You can install is using `sudo gem install xcodeproj`